# Disabling a checkbox by checking another checkbox in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2, vuetify.js

So I have several `checkboxes` and two of them should function like `radiobuttons` meaning that if I click on one, the other one should become disabled and vice versa (I know I can do it using `radiobuttons` but I need to use `checkboxes`). What's the best way to do it?

Here is my code for those two `checkboxes`:

```
<v-checkbox label="Check1" value="Check1" v-model="Check1" ></v-checkbox>

<v-checkbox label="Check2" value="Check2" v-model="Check2" ></v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to handle the `@change` event which will update the `Check1` and `Check2` as follows :

```
  <v-checkbox label="Check1" value="Check1" v-model="Check1" @change="Check2=!Check1"></v-checkbox>

   <v-checkbox label="Check2" value="Check2" v-model="Check2" @change="Check1=!Check2"></v-checkbox>
```

you could check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJXEzM?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1):

Your two values aren't independent of each other; one defines the other. So you should only have one `data` item, and the other can be a settable computed.

```
  data: {
    Check1: true
  },
  computed: {
    Check2: {
      get() {
        return !this.Check1;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.Check1 = !newValue;
      }
    }
  }
```

If you did want them to be not completely linked – say you want to be able to have both of them off – you would make two `data` items and have a `watch` on each that turns the other off when this one is turned on.

```
  data: {
    Check1: true,
    Check2: false
  },
  watch: {
    Check1(nv) { if (nv) { this.Check2 = false; } },
    Check2(nv) { if (nv) { this.Check1 = false; } }
  }
```