# Vue/Bootstrap checkboxes, limit to only one checked at a time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two checkboxes in my Vue template:

```
<div class="form-check form-group">
        <input v-model="isRecurringTask" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Make this a recurring task</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-group">
        <input v-model="isScheduledTask" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="scheduleCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="scheduleCheck">Schedule a task</label>
    </div>
```

They both work properly and call their functions properly, but how should I properly make it so that only one can be checked at a time? I want to do this in the most appropriate way with Vue

Comment: i think you're looking to something like [`this example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733952/disabling-a-checkbox-by-checking-another-checkbox-in-vuetify/53734251#53734251)

Comment: This is literally what radio buttons are for! It would make more sense to style the radio buttons as check boxes, than to make the check boxes act like radio buttons. I would strongly suggest against both options though, and use radio buttons instead.

Comment: @JoshuaDavison  I'm glad you said that: I actually changed type to radio on both, which worked but then both radio buttons were filled and the functionality when selected no longer worked. Maybe I missed something else

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same `v-model` for all radio-buttons which belong to the same group - and to give them distinct values:

```
<template>
<div class="form-check form-group">
  <input v-model.number="typeOfTask" class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="1" id="defaultCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Make this a recurring task
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-group">
  <input v-model.number="typeOfTask" class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="2" id="scheduleCheck">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="scheduleCheck">
      Schedule a task
    </label>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default
  {
    data()
    {
      return {
        typeOfTask: null, // 1 = recurring, 2 = scheduled
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you asking for this example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   radios: [
     { value: 'isRecurringTask', label: 'Make this a recurring task' },
      { value: 'isScheduledTask', label: 'Schedule a task' }
    ],
    radioSelected: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <div     
    v-for="inputRadio in radios"
    class="form-check form-group"
  >
    <input 
      class="form-check-input" 
      v-model="radioSelected"
      type="radio" 
      :value="inputRadio.value" 
      :id="inputRadio.value"
    >
    <label 
      class="form-check-label" 
      :for="inputRadio.value"
    >
      {{ inputRadio.label }}
    </label>
  </div>
  the current input radio value selected is: {{ radioSelected }}
</div>
```